Difference between np.argsort and index_natsorted natural sort
I have the below dataframe and I want to sort naturally by 'time' column.
df = pd.DataFrame({
   "time": ['0hr', '128hr', '72hr', '48hr', '96hr'],
   "value": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
})

df.sort_values(
    by="time",
    key=lambda x: index_natsorted(df["time"])
    
)

I use the natsort.index_natsorted function which is supposed to return the 'time' column in the sequence of ['0hr','48hr','72hr','96hr','128hr'], because the index_natsorted, applied to the given 'time' column, returns a tuple of [0, 3, 2, 4, 1], which suppose to sort the column in the above manner, with 0 in tuple referring to the first element '0hr' of the 'time' column, and the subsequent 3 in tuple referring to the fourth element '48hr' of the 'time' column, and so on...
However the output I got is:
output:
time value
0hr   10
96hr  50
72hr  30
128hr 20
48hr  40


Could someone explain to me why the index_natsorted function will return the 'time' column in this sequence?
Similar to np.argsort, the docs of index_natsorted reads that it " Sorts a sequence naturally, but returns a list of sorted the indexes and not the sorted list itself." So I am curious as to why in this case its returned indices will not sort the elements naturally.

Can you please provide documentation for the index_natsorted function?

@PandaKim OP is referring to natsort.index_natsorted() as is indicated by their tagging. I integrated the link into the question.

Code
The index_natsorted function returns the index in order. The key parameter of the sort_values function re-sorts to fit the returned array, so your method is not correct. The index_natsorted function returns an index, so it is correct to use iloc to index.
import natsort
out = df.iloc[natsort.index_natsorted(df["time"])]


If you want to solve it with Pandas, use the following code
out = df.sort_values(
    by="time",
    key=lambda x: x.str.replace('hr', '').astype('float') 
)


Both numpy.argsort and natsort.index_natsorted have similar functionality of returning an array of indices sorted according to the elements of the original array.  Their difference is they are implemented for different libraries.  For example argsort has some generalizations for higher dimensions and natsort for splitting strings.  Both will sort strings alphabetically by default.
Assuming that your time column is always of the format "[int]hr", I would suggest the following solution to your problem:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "time": ['0hr', '128hr', '72hr', '48hr', '96hr'],
    "value": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
})

df.sort_values(
    by="time",
    key=lambda series: pd.Series([int(t[:-2]) for t in series])
)

Which outputs:
    time  value
0    0hr     10
3   48hr     40
2   72hr     30
4   96hr     50
1  128hr     20


Natsort does natural sorting:
import pandas as pd
from natsort import natsort_key

df.sort_values('time', key = natsort_key)
    time  value
0    0hr     10
3   48hr     40
2   72hr     30
4   96hr     50
1  128hr     20

